# nodejs ExpressJs BackboneJs pushstate

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, pushstate

I've got problemas with `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});` when is actived

I use the backbone router `'example/:id':'test'` and the browser returns me an error

> GET myhost:1337/example/js/views/test.js 404 (Not Found)

I want to rotate with Backbone for example `myhost:1337/example/test` without the necessity to request nodejs.

si, I dunno why,

Could be my server Nodejs?
Or Could be my code that it's not well written?
 Thanks in advance

MY server code is

```
    //var http = require('http');
var path = require('path'),
    express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes/index'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = require('express')();

app.configure(function(){
    //app.set('view options',{layout: false });
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1337);
    app.use(express.bodyParser()),
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(app.router); // you need this line so the .get etc. routes are run and if an error within, then the error is parsed to the ned middleware (your error reporter)
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        if(!err) return next(); // you also need this line
        console.log("error!!!");
        res.send("error!!!");
    });
});

app.get('*',function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/javascript');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.redirect('http://localhost:1337#'+req.url);
});


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something with your server. I'm willing to bet you didn't hold the shift key down when you typed out your route, so you have something like this in your server

```
app.get('example?:id':'test', function() {});
```

When you should have:

```
app.get('example/:id':'test', function() {});
```

This block:

```
app.post('/addPlace?:?',routes.addPlace);
app.get('/searchPlace?:q',routes.searchPlace);
app.post('/showPlace',routes.showPlace);
app.get('/showPlaceById?:id',routes.showPlaceById)
app.post('/deletePlace?:?',routes.deletePlace);
```

See the `?`'s everywhere? This should really be:

```
app.post('/addPlace',routes.addPlace);
app.get('/searchPlace/:q',routes.searchPlace);
app.post('/showPlace',routes.showPlace);
app.get('/showPlaceById/:id',routes.showPlaceById)
app.post('/deletePlace',routes.deletePlace);
```

If you change that, `/showPlaceById/:id` will return what you expect.

Comment: i have this 'example/:id':'test' in fact. But i  doesn´t work. The browser returns me an error

Comment: @oscar That's your code for the backbone router. What's your code in your node.js server?

Comment: I think nodejs detect the URL and its traying to find the files. Im not sure if is that

Comment: @oscar I edited my answer. Your 2 edits are completely inconsistent from one another. I went off the first block of code you posted. Look into what I'm referring to and you'll almost certainly find your answer.

Comment: ok, but If i dont what that nodejs read that. I mean, i want to use int he url  http//myhost/example/test  but idont waant that nodejs read that

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. You wanted to know why it was returning a 404, this is why.

Comment: Any request you make to the host on port `1337` will automatically be handled by the node because that's the way you've set it up.

Comment: But i want to rotate with backbone, so I dont want to request to nodejs every time that I use http//myhost/example/test